# Android creating login and signup form with existing database

Tags: android, sqlite

I already created a database using sqlitebrowser and have connected it to android studio. The database.sqlite is in my assets folder. The question is: how to I create a login and registration form with existing database. I have been searching and watching video but none of them teaches. I have been struggling. Any tutorial links related to that would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Basically, I have created a simple application. I'm still learning android.
I have created 3 menu tabs and have connected my database.sqlite to android studio with the help of this link.
*http://developinginandroid.blogspot.sg/2014/01/connect-db-sqlite-to-android-with.html*

I am able to retrieve data from my database. This is my application when i run.
[Able to retrieve data from my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZVmF.png)

So, I want to create a login/registration form using existing database. i have created a table using sqlite browser called "User" with field: Name,password,email,age
Once login successfully, it open a new activity which is my 3 menu tabs.

Any tutorial link regarding would be appreciated.

Comment: First, you have to load the prepopulated database from assets, instead of create a new one. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think this is *not very Android related*. I think this is more *programming techniques related*. You need to develop a strategy in order to determine when the user is logged in or not. Android provides you the SQLite DB, it's ok. But is your responsability to determine how to use that DB and what to do with it. Do you know SQL? Now is time to use it.